# iOS - How To Rotate imageView 360 degree From its center

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uikit

i want to rotate my imageView in my iOS app 360 degree from its center

(when my label text is "hello")

please help me

```
if ([myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"hello"] == YES)
{
    //here i want the imageView to rotate

}
```

Comment: Rotate percent? Degrees? 360 goes back to where you started. Image of what you want? What did you try and what did it do wrong?

Comment: it is a star (yellow star)

Comment: So you want an animation which is a 360 degree rotation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406166/ios-a-complete-360-degree-rotation-using-block-not-cabasicanimation

Comment: YES i want it to rotate 360 degree

Comment: You won't even notice a 360 degree rotation because 360%360=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want it animated. Otherwise, there is no change in image view.

```
#define DEGREES_IN_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_IN_RADIANS(360));

} completion:nil];
```

Comment: this will typed in the if block right

Comment: define statement will go along with import statements. The rest will go inside your IF loop. Make sure that you change imageView (in imageView.image) to whatever name you have provided in your code. Also, change 'duration' to whatever time you would like.

Comment: be with me one minute

Comment: i 'll try it and tell you

Comment: the compiler makes an error symbol beside this line of code  imageView.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_IN_RADIANS(360));

Comment: What is the error? Did you add #define statement?

Comment: yeah the compiler says that property transform not found on object type 'UIImage *'

Comment: You rotate UIImageView.image, not UIImage. You need to have UIImageView and you then assign <your imageview>.image = <the image you want to display>. Then, you rotate <your imageview>.image. If still finding difficulty, post your code.

Comment: My bad. Change from imageView.image.transform to imageView.transform. It should work.

Comment: if ([myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"hello"])
    {
        
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(320 * M_PI / 180.0);
        } completion:nil];
    }

Comment: this the code that i have written but the imageView don't rotate also

Comment: No , No , it is my fault , it is now rotating thank you

Comment: but how to increase the rotation speed

Comment: You can adjust duration to increase or decrease speed. Check out animateWithDuration:animations in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:

Comment: +1 for the radians conversion

Comment: The first line should be: `#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)` (no semi-colon and parenthesis around the `x`). The current code produces this error: `Implicit declaration of function 'DEGREES_TO_RADIANS' is invalid in C99`.

Answer (score 1):

`myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI / 180.0);`

If you want ti have it animated, wrap it in an animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

} completion:nil];
```

Comment: what i will type in if ([myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"hello"] == YES)
{
    //here i want the imageView to rotate

}

Comment: what i will type in if blocks

Comment: Just put the friggin code I posted in there.

Comment: in the if blocks right?

Comment: be With me one moment

Comment: ................. but i want the image to be rotated

Comment: Then try it with 90 degrees maybe. You can hardly notice a 360 degrees rotation. And if you ever use more than 3 dots in a row again I will stop helping you.

Comment: i think you didn't understand me

Comment: Then please learn to speak proper English and how to express yourself. Good luck solving your problem.